# How to lightweight register a periodic event?

Tags: c#, timer

I want some code to be triggered every second. Usually, I'd create a Timer and link to its event. I wondered if there is a better way. Maybe without the requirement to implement IDisposable.

**Edit:** My main concern is LoC. I don't feel like writing an entire class when something along the lines of this could work, too:

```
System.RegisterPeriodicEvent (1000, () => { Syso("asdf"); };
```

In my dreams this event is automatically unregistered as soon as the current threat terminates.

I get the feeling that I should just write a class which implements the above method.

Comment: In which context? In a windows application? In a single or multi-threaded application? What's wrong (and non-lightweight) about IDisposable?

Comment: Yes, Windows application. Multithreaded. Nothing wrong with IDisposable, just many LoC with few actual value.

Comment: I consider preventing memory leaks to be of quite significant value.

Comment: And with `using() {}`, not many LoC either.

Comment: Matthew, yes, of course I don't want memleaks. Using Timers, I have to create an entire class which implements IDisposable, that's like 50 lines of code compared to 1 lines in the example given.

Comment: In the case above, you've got a memory leak anyway. There'd be no way of deregistering the event (since it's a lambda), so you've effectively just setup a timer and let it go anyway.

Comment: Anyway, to answer the question, no, there's nothing built-in. Sure, you could implement something like this if you wanted, it's not terribly difficult.

Comment: I disagree on the no way of deregistering the event part, but I will take your advice and just use a Timer for now.

Comment: Unless the function you described above returns some identifier, then it is, because you can't later reference the lambda directly. Unless there was some `DeregisterAll()` method of course.

Comment: DeregisterAll on death of thread, I imagine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it ain't broke, don't try to fix it.

Running `x` piece of code every `y` amount of time is what a timer does, and it does it very well.

As for avoiding `IDisposable`, not really, not without creating memory leaks anyway. The only two ways I can think of to do this is with kernel primitive timers (which need to be released, `IDisposable`), or with a thread and `Thread.Sleep()` or similar (and then you need to kill the thread when you're done, again `IDisposable`).

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly a lightweight way of doing things, but Retlang has very nice timer functionality.  In particular, it deals up front with nasty threading issues (by serializing the calls) and allows you to interleave event driven work with timers.

Best of all, you dispose of the fiber and you dispose of the event.  It's not trivial though: you've got to design your code around the API (which later on you'll regard as worth it, but at first looks like a pain in the neck).